# Saving XMLHttpRequest.responseText in a variable for GTM

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-tag-manager

I'm quite new to JS and i have a problem. I'm trying to get XMLHttpRequest.responseText to use it as variable in GTM. The url I'm sending request is an endpoint.

```
function httpGetAsync (url, callback) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
    callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.send();

}

httpGetAsync("https://www.example.pl/example-uid-cookie", function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

The answear I'm getting looks like below and I would like to have the value instead of undefined:

[image]

Comment: But... you have the value. The console clearly logs `550269.....` The `undefined` you see is only what the `httpGetAsync` function returns (nothing), not the result of the HTTP call. The HTTP call is good and returns what you expect. If you add `return "hello"` at the end of the `httpGetAsync` function, then the console will log `"hello"` followed by `550269.....`.

Comment: Also all this `XMLHttpRequest` and `if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)` etc. literature feels very 2000's :) You should have a look at [fetch](https://javascript.info/fetch)

Comment: @JeremyThille, he wants the value available for use within GTM, being able to log to the console does not help with that - the typical way in GTM would be to do a push to the datalayer array in the response callback.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GTM, but once we have the value we want, the job is pretty much done, isn't it? Just send the value to whatever function